# Node JS 6.9 and angular CLI version compatibility

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have a restriction of using node JS version 6.9.1. I am getting many problems, while using angular cli quick start steps.

1. after ng serve, browser page will be white, no error in console.
2. npm start works, but if i change some style/file browser do not not refresh.
3. if i make any style change, webpack compiled successfully message comes but webserver fails to load page.

When I follow the quick start steps with latest nodejs it works like a charm. Can any one help me in telling, what are the versions (npm, angular-cli), I should use to run it ?

Like

Answer (score 2):

Each Angular/Cli version has limited its compatibility of node versions below a specified release. If you *have* to use a specific version of node then your best bet would be to find a previous version of the Angular/Cli that will play nicely.

[Here you can find all the versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli/v/6.0.8?activeTab=versions) and from there, pick one a little further back in the list and then do a search in google for "Angular/cli version x.x.x node compatibility" to see if there are any known issues.

Once you pick a version that looks good, run

`npm install -g @angular/cli@<your version number>`.

Once the install is complete run `ng help` and you'll get feedback right away if the version is still incompatible and you can try a different version.

Just make sure you get rid of the installs you aren't using with `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli@<your version number>`

Comment: How it is possible that there is no list with NodeJS vs AngularCLI compatibility...

Answer (score 0):

for see if angular-cli is compatibility whit your node version installed you can see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli/v/6.0.8?activeTab=versions, for example, I have installed node 6.11.2 and I have to use: npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.0